# port out of range:-1 .Failed to notify build listener

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, gradle

what's possible reason ?
gradle :6.7
and android studio version : Android studio arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

**Question : Latest version of android studio is incompatible with gradle 6 ?**

If not then what's possible problem of this compilation error ?

```
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the latest version of gradle supported by Android Studio. In the gradle-wrapper.properties file in the gradle\wrapper folder, change the line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.0-bin.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`
Also, update the Android Gradle Plugin